# How to print a range of records from a csv file in python

Tags: python

```
list_input = input("please enter a date in the format mm/dd/yyyy")

df = pd.read_csv("covid_19_data.csv")

index = df.index
new_val = df["ObservationDate"] == list_input
b = index[new_val]
    
new_output = b.tolist()
new_list = [x + 1 for x in new_output]
```

So that is my code for finding what records have a certain date that the user inputted, how do I now print all those records with the same date using the list I have created that holds all the indices

Answer (score 0):

```
for record in new_list:
    print(record)
```

Comment: `print(record)`, not `print(element)`

Comment: Yes، sorry I fixed it.

Comment: that just re prints the list I have already created, my goal is to print each record in a csv file that shares the same value as the user input. So far as mentioned before I have been able to get where each of the records are but I do not know how to print them. As I have a list of values that indicate which records need to be printed

Comment: use `with open('your_file_name.csv', mode='w') as file:`

Comment: check this link for more details on how to use it: https://realpython.com/python-csv/#writing-csv-files-with-csv

Comment: not sure If I am missing something or I just lack the knowledge, Still haven't figured it out ahaha